# Is there a python module which provides entry points that wrap the openssh client?

Tags: python, ssh, openssh

Is there a Python module which provides provides remote control functions by launching subprocesses implementing the ssh command line interface? The kind of functions that would be useful include:

- run this command on that machine, and return exit code, stdout and stderr or raise an exception after a timeout
- test whether a directory exists on that machine
- write these bytes to that filename on that machine

I am aware of [paramiko](http://www.lag.net/paramiko)  and [Conch](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/wiki/TwistedConch). However, I would like programs using this module to be able to use the openssh [ControlMaster](http://www.linux.com/archive/feed/54498) feature that reuses long running existing ssh connections to target machines. Otherwise the SSH connection set up time can dominate run time. This approach also allows other programs that implement the openssh command line interface to be used without rewriting the programs using the module.

Answer (score 3):

You might find Python's [Fabric](http://fabfile.org/) right for your needs.  It looks like it uses paramiko but it is smart about caching connections, as documented in the [execution model](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.0.1/usage/execution.html#connections).

It won't use an existing long-running connection though.

Answer (score 1):

Some of what you're talking about sounds like you want to use rsync, specifically your functions of "test whether a directory exists on that machine", "write these bytes to that filename on that machine", "run a callback every time lines gets written to that file on that machine". You could either use some of the existing [Python-rsync](http://www.owlfish.com/software/utils/RSyncBackup/) bridges people have provided, or create one of your own.

There is no way you'll be able to keep a long-running SSH tunnel open without having a daemon process to maintain it. Both paramiko and Conch support SSH channels, which could easily be run in a daemon process just like a classic SSH port redirection.

Comment: openssh in ControlMaster mode is, in effect, a daemon.

Comment: I do understand that. Are you going to fire off that initial connection manually and expect it to be running, or do you wish to have Python control this process as well?

Comment: That's an interesting question. There is already code in openssh to fire off the master and keep the connection open for a while as needed, but that approach doesn't necessarily make clear the difference between an ssh server that doesn't respond and a command that takes ages to finish, which happens to be important to me in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

I still haven't found any code I can use so wrote the version below. I'm still keen to find an open source module that does this kind of thing.

```
"""Remote control a machine given an ssh client on Linux"""

from pwd import getpwuid
from socket import socket, AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, error
from os import getuid, write, close, unlink, read
import select, errno
from subprocess import PIPE, Popen, check_call
from time import time, sleep
from tempfile import mkstemp

def whoami():
    """figure out user ID"""
    return getpwuid(getuid()).pw_name

def arg_escape(text):
    """Escape things that confuse shells"""
    return text.replace('(', '\\(').replace(')', '\\)')

def try_open_socket(socket_name):
    """can we talk to socket_name?"""
    sock = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM)
    try:
        sock.connect(socket_name)
    except error:
        return False
    else:
        return True

class ProcessTimeoutError(Exception):
    """Indicates that a process failed to finish in alotted time"""
    pass

class ConnectionTimeoutError(Exception):
    """Indicates that it was not possible to connect in alotted time"""

class CalledProcessError(Exception):
    """Indicates non-zero exit of a process we expected to exit cleanly"""

def local_run_with_timeout(command, timeout=60, check=True):
    """Run a command with a timeout after which it will be SIGKILLed.

    If check is set raise CalledProcessError if the command fails.

    Based on the standard library subprocess.Popen._communicate_with_poll.
    """
    process = Popen(command, shell=False, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
    poller = select.poll()
    start = time()
    fd2file = {}
    content = {}
    for stream in [process.stdout, process.stderr]:
        poller.register(stream.fileno(), select.POLLIN | select.POLLPRI)
        fd2file[stream.fileno()] = stream
        content[stream] = ''
    vout = lambda: content[process.stdout]
    verr = lambda: content[process.stderr]
    while fd2file:
        delta = time() - start
        if delta > timeout:
            process.kill()
            raise ProcessTimeoutError(command, timeout, vout(), verr())
        try:
            ready = poller.poll(timeout-delta)
        except select.error, exc:
            if exc.args[0] == errno.EINTR:
                continue
            raise
        for fileno, mode in ready:
            if mode & (select.POLLIN | select.POLLPRI):
                data = read(fileno, 4096)
                content[fd2file[fileno]] += data
                if data:
                    continue
            fd2file[fileno].close()
            fd2file.pop(fileno)
            poller.unregister(fileno)
    process.wait()
    if check and process.returncode != 0:
        raise CalledProcessError(process.returncode, delta, command,
                                 vout(), verr())
    return (process.returncode, vout(), verr())



class Endpoint:
    """Perform operations on a remote machine"""
    def __init__(self, host, user=None, process_timeout=10,
                 connection_timeout=20):
        self.host = host
        self.user = user
        self.target = ((self.user+'@') if self.user else '') + self.host
        self.process_timeout = process_timeout
        self.connection_timeout = connection_timeout

    def start(self):
        """Start the SSH connection and return the unix socket name.

        Requires http://sourceforge.net/projects/sshpass/ and
        http://software.clapper.org/daemonize/ to be installed
        """
        socket_name = '/tmp/' + whoami() + '-ssh-' + self.target
        if not try_open_socket(socket_name):
            check_call(['daemonize', '/usr/bin/ssh',
                        '-N', '-M', '-S', socket_name, self.target])
            start = time()
            while not try_open_socket(socket_name):
                delta = time() - start
                if delta > self.connection_timeout:
                    raise ConnectionTimeoutError(delta, self.target)
                sleep(1)
        return socket_name

    def call(self, command, timeout=None, check=False):
        """Run command with timeout"""
        if not timeout:
            timeout = self.process_timeout
        socket_name = self.start()
        if type(command) == type(''):
            command = command.split()
        command_escape = [arg_escape(x) for x in command]
        command_string = ' '.join(command_escape)

        return local_run_with_timeout(
            ['/usr/bin/ssh', '-S', socket_name,
             self.target, command_string], timeout=timeout, check=check)
    def check_call(self, command, timeout=None):
        """Run command with timeout"""
        exitcode, stdout, stderr = self.call(command, timeout=timeout,
                                             check=True)
        return stdout, stderr

    def isdir(self, directory):
        """Return true if a directory exists"""
        return 'directory\n' in self.call(['stat', directory])[1]

    def write_file(self, content, filename):
        """Store content on filename"""
        handle, name = mkstemp()
        try:
            write(handle, content)
            close(handle)
            socket_name = self.start()
            exitcode, stdout, stderr = local_run_with_timeout(
                ['/usr/bin/scp', '-o', 'ControlPath='+socket_name,
                 '-o', 'ControlMaster=auto', name, self.target+':'+filename],
                timeout=self.process_timeout, check=True)
        finally:
            unlink(name)

def test_check_call():
    """Run through some test cases. """
    tep = Endpoint('localhost')
    assert 'dev' in tep.check_call('ls /')[0]
    assert tep.call('false')[0] != 0

def test_basic_timeout():
    """Ensure timeouts trigger"""
    import pytest # "easy_install pytest" FTW
    start = time()
    with pytest.raises(ProcessTimeoutError):
        Endpoint('localhost').call('sleep 5', timeout=0.2)
    assert not (time()-start > 3)

def test_timeout_output():
    """check timeouts embed stdout"""
    import pytest # "easy_install pytest" FTW
    with pytest.raises(ProcessTimeoutError):
        Endpoint('localhost').call('find /', timeout=0.2)

def test_non_zero_exit():
    """chek check_call raises an CalledProcessError on timeout"""
    import pytest # "easy_install pytest" FTW
    with pytest.raises(CalledProcessError):
        Endpoint('localhost').check_call('false')

def test_fs():
    """check filesystem operations"""
    tep = Endpoint('localhost')
    assert tep.isdir('/usr')
    assert not tep.isdir(str(time()))
    tep.write_file('hello world', '/tmp/test')
    tep.check_call(['grep','hello','/tmp/test'])
```